# If statement for specific event.request

Tags: javascript, if-statement, service-worker-events

I have the following code in my service worker index.js to show all the event request urls:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', functin(event) {
  console.log(event.request.url);
});
```

With this all the request url are listed in the console. What i need is a simple if statement to check if the request url ends with .jpg. so far i tried it with `if === '.jpg'` or variations or with `image/jpg`
but it does not do the trick.

Comment: “Ends with `.jpg`” implies `event.request.url.endsWith(".jpg")`, not `event.request.url === ".jpg"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [String.prototype.endsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith):

```
if (event.request.url.endsWith('.jpg')) {
    console.log(event.request.url);
}
```

If this code is going to be running the browser though, be warned that Internet Explorer does not yet support this function, so you may need to use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith#Polyfill).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, thats exactly what i needed and it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

for example

```
if (event.request.url.endsWith('.jpg')) {
    console.log(event.request.url);
    //handling response you may replace it with somthing
     event.respondWith(fetch('/imgs/avatar.jpg'));
}
```